# JSON data from server could not be parsed - data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I just have done test to see if my aplication can handle special charcters.

In PHP form I add data to MySQL as folow:

`"test"` | `'test'` | `" £ $ % ^ & * ( )` | `'test' "test"`

data have been escaped and in MySQL looks like this:

`\\\"test\\\"` | `\\\'test\\\'` | `! \\\" £ $ % ^ & * ( )` | `\\\'test\\\' \\\"test\\\"`

that goes to JSON like that:

```
[
    "\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\"",
    "\\\\\\\'test\\\\\\\'",
    "! \\\\\\\" £ $ % ^ & * ( )",
    "\\\\\\\'test\\\\\\\' \\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\"",
]
```

that can't be parset in JSON so I checked above in JSONLint.com and I get that error:

```
Parse error on line 2:
..."test\\\\\\\"",    "\\\\\\\'test\\\\\\\
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

I know that can be fixed but not sure where?

1. in PHP before I send to MySQL?
2. in MySQL query before sent to MySQL database?
3. in PHP before goes to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

> in PHP before I send to MySQL?

Answer is prepared statments. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

> in MySQL query before sent to MySQL database?

Answer is prepared statments. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

> in PHP before goes to JSON?

Answer is [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Don't escape same data twice.

Comment: I'm using this Singleton MySQL PHP Class: [link](http://www.ricocheting.com/code/php/mysql-database-class-wrapper-v3)

Comment: Too bad this class is using deprecated `mysql_` functions